# Parsing json data to android canvas

Tags: json, android-canvas

i'm new to android programming and working on a project in which i'm trying to draw a rectangle onto the android canvas depending on the value in json file. Following is the link to my json file
http://smartparkingmanagement.com/parkingwebservice.php

What i'm trying to do will be something like:

if(parkingslotNumber =="SLOT-1" && status = "AVAILABLE"){

canvas.drawRect(10,10,50,40,paint)

}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Creating Custom Views article on the Android Developers site, they explain what you can do with custom Views and how to draw to the canvas.

On a side note, one thing I noticed in your question is you are doing

```
if(parkingslotNumber == "SLOT-1")
```

This will return false. You want to call someString.equals(otherString) for String equality comparisons as such:

```
if("SLOT-1".equals(parkingslotNumber))
```